# SQL Server : count date with biweekly date

Tags: sql-server

I having trouble to count items biweekly (end at Friday)

Table is like:

```
+------------+------------+
| ItemNumber |    Date    |
+------------+------------+
|        235 | 2016-03-02 |
|        456 | 2016-03-04 |
|        454 | 2016-03-08 |
|        785 | 2016-03-10 |
|        123 | 2016-03-15 |
|        543 | 2016-03-18 |
|        863 | 2016-03-20 |
|        156 | 2016-03-26 |
+------------+------------+
```

Result:

```
+-------+------------+
| Total |   biWeek   |
+-------+------------+
|     4 | 2016-03-11 |
|     3 | 2016-03-25 |
|     1 | 2016-04-08 |
+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, something like this should work:

```
select 
  sum(1), 
  dateadd(day, ceiling(datediff(day,4, [Date]) / 14.0) * 14, 4) 
from
  yourtable
group by 
  dateadd(day, ceiling(datediff(day,4, [Date]) / 14.0) * 14, 4)
```

This calculates the date difference in days to "day 4" aka. 5.1.1900, divides it with 14 (rounding up) and multiplies by 14 to get biweeks and then adds that to the "day 4".

Comment: This is great. Just small issue. When there is no date during two weeks period, that Friday date will not show. For example if in weeks of '2016-03-25' and it has no item, I want to show Total: 0; Date : '2016-03-25'. right now it won't display '2016-03-25' if I have not data for that week

Comment: @sylanter then you need to use a date table (or a tally) to populate the missing dates, for example by joining it to the result of this select

Comment: Thank. That is what I thought. I just try to see if there is a better way.

Comment: @James Z just out of curiosity, why did you use "day 4"?! Why not "day 0"?!

Comment: @pedrambashiri OP wanted a week that ends on Friday.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT anyColumn, …, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateColumn) / 2 * 2 , 0) as biweekly
FROM table
WHERE condition
GROUP BY anyColumn, …, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateColumn) / 2 * 2 , 0)
```

This calculates how many weeks dateColumn is far from date 0, then the quotient of dividing this difference by 2 is multiplied by 2 which gives you 2 week intervals. By adding these 2 week intervals to date 0, you will get 2 week periods.

Comment: Done sir! Thanks for the comment.